# Is it legal to use the Source Engine out of Steam?

Tags: legal, valve, steam, source-engine

I would like to create a game that uses the Source Engine on Desura, the problem is that I am afraid that it is illegal to use the Source Engine in other platforms are not managed by Valve

Comment: This is really not a great place for asking legal advice. Contact Valve directly, and I can assure you they will be more than happy to provide you with guidance on how to use their software properly, and how to avoid using improperly. I'm not saying your question sucks, i'm just saying that no one here except for the valve team could provide you with authentic information. The best we could do is point you in their direction.

Comment: Contact them: http://www.valvesoftware.com/contact/ I also think you'll find it impossible to use the Source SDK that comes free with your Source games outside of Steam. There's no way to produce an executable from those tools, and they're simply for modding existing games (although it some cases it could be a complete conversion). The Source Engine can be licensed to make games with, but it's not free.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can as long as you license the engine, with terms permitting it.

The version of Source that comes with the games that you purchase is for modding those existing games, and you won't be able to produce executables with it (and if you do manage to, you're going to run into some other more costly problems).

[Interested in licensing Source, refer to this handy information sheet.](http://www.valvesoftware.com/SOURCE_InfoSheet.pdf)

Comment: You are likely to be very heavily incentivized to releasing on Steam though.

Comment: That information sheet appears to be about the Source engine, not the licensing it.

Comment: @Byte56 - Yeah, it's what they provide :p As the second page says it's NDA'd but they give a link.

Comment: When I was researching for an answer to this, I found people in the forums complaining that they had been emailing asking about it with no response. Seems like it might be hard to get information.